# Exporting from PostGis using Ogr2Ogr - "Unable to open datasource"

Tags: postgis, geojson, ogr2ogr

Wrestling with Ogr2Ogr again here. I have managed to use it to import a geojson file into a PostGis database, can query and manipulate the database layer. However, when I try and export the database table to a new file I get the message: "Unable to open datasource 'myexport.geojson' with the following drivers"

GeoJson is in the list of drivers, and the layer is in PostGis.

> .\ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "PG:host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" "C:\Temp\output.geojson"

Comment: You should only ask one question. /u/bugmenot123 answered your initial question, you should accept it as correct and ask another question.

Comment: I've rolled back the question to the state in which it was answered.  Once a question has been answered, if you have another question, then ask a new question for it.  If the original provides any useful background then you can always include a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

ogr2ogr expects the destination datasource before the source in the invocation:

```
Usage: ogr2ogr (...)
               dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
```

Your line is in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Now I'm running into problems getting just a specific table set of data. Will add update.

Comment: That is a different problem, please open a new question for that.

Comment: What's wrong with "select * from with_id"? Is the table listed if you run `ogrinfo "PG:host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" `?